# NewMailEx event is not firing for each mail?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-2010

I am developing an application, in which I need to read the content (mail body) of the incoming mail. For this, I am using below code to trigger the event, every time when new mail comes -

```
outLookApp.NewMailEx += new ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(MailExtractor.outLookApp_NewMailEx);
```

But `NewMailEx` event is not firing for few mails. It seems it’s not firing when two or three mails come at the same time.
Theoretically it should fire for each mail that comes in MS Outlook inbox.
I am using MS Outlook 2010.

How can I assure triggering of `NewMailEx` event for each and every mail that is coming?

Comment: No, that event is not fired for _every_ mailbox. If you want to serial process each single e-mail I suggest you use the **ItemAdd** event in the **Inbox** collection (see MSDN).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304%28v=office.11%29.aspx) "This event (NewMailEx) passes a list of entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired". But if you tested it and it doesn't that's what count.

Using ItemAdd is not the best choice as it also may not fire on each mail as you can read in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171270%28v=office.11%29.aspx). Also this works on a per folder basis so if the user has server rules that moves the mail to different folder you will need to handle multiple folders.

My solution to to similar requirement was using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) library where the [Store](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm) class has OnMessageCreatedEx event that is fired on each item created in the store.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old now, but I ran into the same issue.  Although `NewMailEx` seems to be more reliable than `NewMail` and `Items.ItemsAdd` it's still unreliable when multiple messages are coming in at the same time, as the documentation states.

It seems there's a free add-in available ([MAPI Store Accessor](http://www.add-in-express.com/products/mapi-store-events.php)) that handles multiple send/receive events better, but there can be a long delay before notification (up to 30 minutes).

If that's not acceptable for what you're trying to do, check out [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/) for a nice article on how to roll your own more reliable solution.